# How to add reccurance option to 'W' and 'W(number)'

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, intervals

I want to add handling reccurance of 'W' and 'W1' 'W2' etc.. the (number) specifies appearance of the meeting throughout weeks. So for example date of the meeting is 02.07.2023 and interval is W3 then another meeting appears at 23.07.2023

I tried using my weekCount() function which i took from other post and changing value of `weeksDiff % 4 === 0` to `weeksDiff % 1 === 0` but it didnt work

My API Endpoint:

```
app.get('/checkAvailability', (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { ids, date } = req.query;
    const selectedIds = ids.split(',');

    const results = [];

    fs.createReadStream('4busy.csv')
      .pipe(csv())
      .on('data', (data) => {
        results.push(data);
      })
      .on('end', () => {
        const occupiedSlots = results
          .filter((availability) => selectedIds.includes(availability.personId))
          .map((availability) => {
            const interval = availability.interval.toUpperCase();
            const startDate = new Date(availability.date);
            const currentDate = new Date(date);

            if (interval === 'D') {
              return {
                slot: `${availability.start} - ${availability.end}`,
                personId: availability.personId,
                end: availability.end,
              };
            } else if (interval === 'M') {
              const weeksDiff = weekCount(currentDate) - weekCount(startDate);
              if (weeksDiff % 4 === 0 && startDate <= currentDate) {
                return {
                  slot: `${availability.start} - ${availability.end}`,
                  personId: availability.personId,
                  end: availability.end,
                };
              }
            } else if (interval === 'N') {
              const availableDate = new Date(availability.date);
              if (availableDate.getTime() === currentDate.getTime()) {
                return {
                  slot: `${availability.start} - ${availability.end}`,
                  personId: availability.personId,
                  end: availability.end,
                };
              }
            }
          })
          .filter((slot) => slot !== undefined);

          console.log('Occupied Slots:', occupiedSlots); // Add this line to check the occupiedSlots array

        // Sort occupied slots by 'start' time in ascending order
        occupiedSlots.sort((a, b) => {
          const aTime = parseInt(a.slot.split(' - ')[0].split(':')[0]) * 60 + parseInt(a.slot.split(' - ')[0].split(':')[1]);
          const bTime = parseInt(b.slot.split(' - ')[0].split(':')[0]) * 60 + parseInt(b.slot.split(' - ')[0].split(':')[1]);
          return aTime - bTime;
        });

        // Function to convert minutes to time format (e.g., 10:00)
        function slotTimeToString(minutes) {
          const hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
          const mins = minutes % 60;
          return `${hours.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${mins.toString().padStart(2, '0')}`;
        }

        // Find the maximum end time among all occupied slots
        let maxEndTime = 0;
        occupiedSlots.forEach((slot) => {
          const endTimeMinutes = parseInt(slot.end.split(':')[0]) * 60 + parseInt(slot.end.split(':')[1]);
          if (endTimeMinutes > maxEndTime) {
            maxEndTime = endTimeMinutes;
          }
        });

        // Check if there is at least a 1-hour gap between the last occupied slot's 'end' time and the end of the day (18:00)
        const endOfDayTime = 18 * 60; // Convert 18:00 to minutes
        const earliestAvailableTimes = []; // Move declaration here
        if (endOfDayTime - maxEndTime >= 60) {
          earliestAvailableTimes.push(slotTimeToString(maxEndTime));
        }

        // Find all possible earliest available times after considering occupied slots
        for (let i = 0; i < occupiedSlots.length - 1; i++) {
          const currentSlotEndTime = occupiedSlots[i].end;
          const nextSlotStartTime = occupiedSlots[i + 1].slot.split(' - ')[0];
          const aTime = parseInt(currentSlotEndTime.split(':')[0]) * 60 + parseInt(currentSlotEndTime.split(':')[1]);
          const bTime = parseInt(nextSlotStartTime.split(':')[0]) * 60 + parseInt(nextSlotStartTime.split(':')[1]);

          // Check if there is at least a 1-hour gap between the current slot's end time and the next slot's start time
          if (bTime - aTime >= 60) {
            earliestAvailableTimes.push(slotTimeToString(aTime));
          }
        }

        if (earliestAvailableTimes.length > 0) {
          console.log('Earliest Available Times:', earliestAvailableTimes); // Add this line to check earliestAvailableTimes
          res.json({ isAvailable: false, occupiedSlots, earliestAvailableTimes });
        } else {
          res.json({ isAvailable: true, message: 'Person is all day free' });
        }   
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
});
```

My .csv file example:

```
personId,date,start,end,interval,slot
1,2023-07-17,7:15,7:30,W2,1
1,2023-07-18,7:30,7:45,W3,2
1,2023-07-19,9:00,9:30,W4,3
1,2023-07-20,8:00,9:00,W5,4
```